# messagebox showing question marks in JNI

Tags: c++

I have written a JNI code which calls a c native Dll. In my dll- functionX I have a messsagebox with utf8 characters shown below:

```
string aboutStr = " به این برنامه خوش آمدید";
string aboutCaption = "درباره";

MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)(aboutStr.c_str()), (LPCTSTR)(aboutCaption.c_str()), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
```

When in a java tester, via JNI I call functionX, the messagebox shows question mark instead of persian characters.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Windows uses UTF-16, so you need to convert that UTF-8 `c_str()` into its UTF-16 equivalent. There are examples here, as well as on other sites.

Comment: You can never cast a string like that, you'll get Chinese.  The question marks were generated earlier, probably by your text editor.  Use one that can properly save source code in utf-8 with a BOM.  Favor std::wstring.